# How do I permanently disable youtube autoplay feature?

Tags: youtube

I want to disable this very annoying youtube autoplay feature on my web browser. I try to disable it using youtube UI but after some time it turns on and autoplay starts working again! I am using Firefox 70 on Ubuntu. The answer from 2015 on this site doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: There is a toggle above the "play next" list on the right.

Answer (score 1):

On the left of your playing video there is a list of videos that will be played next. At the top there of that list there is a toggle switch to enable or disable autoplay.

This image shows the switch in disabled mode:

[image]

Comment: "I try to disable it using youtube UI but after some time it turns on and autoplay starts working again! I am using Firefox 70 on Ubuntu."

Comment: It is a cookie maintained option. Do you clear your cookies regularly?

Comment: no, but i want to maintain autoplay disabled even after clearing cookies?

Comment: That is not possible I am afraid.

Comment: I believe this is possible with some javascript magic. I just can't figure out what exactly to do and need an advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with you, I can't stand this feature.  I don't log in to Youtube and I browse in private mode so autoplay is enabled every time I close the browser.

I wrote a userscript that checks if autoplay is enabled every 10 seconds, and disables it if so:

https://openuserjs.org/scripts/thomper/Disable_Youtube_autoplay

The usual applies: no warranty, have only tested it on Firefox with TamperMonkey (Works On My Machine™), etc.

Though if it doesn't work for you, you can open an issue on OpenUserJS and I might have time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to require an extension now. The current UI for YouTube has the auto-play toggle built into to player. It is always on by default each time you go to the site after having left. After several tries I found "Disable YouTube Auto Play" which still works and doesn't try to do anything else. I am not linking because google may very well break things again in the future.

Comment: That is because youtube/google wants it to be enabled by default, so you spend more time with it!

Comment: This? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-youtube-auto-play/

Comment: I think that's the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue since yesterday, I had to download and extension. I have no idea why Youtube autoplay is checked by default.